# Setting table width to 100%, without table-layout: fixed

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

What I'm trying to do is to have a line with two parts, and the last part should be always visible while using `text-overflow: ellipsis` for the first one. Like this :

```
[[foo][bar]       ]
[[lorem i...][bar]]
```

So I used `display: table` for the row and `display: table-cell` for the parts. And it works fine I add `table-layout: fixed` to the row, but that leaves empty space in the second cell.

Here is the fiddle containing what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/ybouhjira/2vWKm/1/

Comment: hmm, I'm not getting it - your fiddle doesn't look like the example here - maybe that's just on chrome?  I dunno..

Comment: I edited it with the correct link, I'm using chrome too

Answer (score 0):

It depend on **#wrapper width** 
go change wrapper width to 400px 
and add this code

```
#cell1 {
    width: 20%;
}
#cell2 {
    width: 99%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2vWKm/2/

Comment: No I want it To work with that width and I can't have a percentage for each cell.